# is "Capilano Pale Ale" still being produced and is it possible to get it in the States?

Tags: ale

is "Capilano Pale Ale" still being produced and is it possible to get it in the States?I'm referring to the Vancouver, British Colombia, microbrew.

Answer (score 2):

My research suggests that Capilano Pale Ale is **no longer brewed**.

[This Vancouver Archives article](http://www.vancouverarchives.ca/2012/05/17/beer-in-vancouver/) on beer in Vancouver suggests that the Capilano brewery was taken over by Molson in 1958. Searching the address given ([1550 Burrard Street](https://www.google.com/#q=1550+burrard+street%2C+vancouver)), I found that Molson still occupies the space. Very little else comes up when I search for Capilano Brewery or Capilano Pale Ale.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for investigating, but I wouldn't really depend on that 1958 date. I was in Vancouver 1999 and that's when I had the Capilano Pale Ale. I might go back this summer, if so I'm going to try to hunt it down.

Comment: Hope you're able to find it again! In this era of all kinds of beer tracking, I'm surprised it didn't come up on RateBeer or BeerAdvocate.

Comment: Well, I haven't to Vancouver yet, so I haven't been able to check, so I still don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my own question. I was in Vancouver a few months ago, went to the same exact place where I had had the Capilano pale ale years ago (the restaurant on the top of the mountain where the tram goes), and can definitely say they don't carry it, had never even heard of it (younger wait staff). So, it would seem it doesn't exist anymore.